# Is this sentence correctly using the word "propagating"?

Tags: word-usage

I'm using propagating as another word of saying spreading.

The sentence "However, my upper-level executive clients encounter technical issues propagating to the customer base and affecting the organization's business goals on a larger scale. "

Comment: Propagating what?  (One could actually read it as meaning that they wish to inseminate their clients -- though that would be a stretch.)

Comment: I was talking about technical issues affecting the customers. Maybe propagating is not the right word?

Comment: I think you need to reword it.

Comment: Could you tell me how?

Comment: Maybe *spilling into*, *migrating to* or *replicating to*.

Answer (score 1):

You're using it to mean *spreading* or *disseminating* or *distributing*.

That's okay, but it's a mouthful. Are you sure you want to use it? It's wordy. The whole sentence is. It's the first-draft syndrome. It's fine to rough something out that way, but it's wise to go back and do some tough editing—especially shortening.

It takes time, but when you're writing to be read, it pays.

For instance, does "on a larger scale" add meaning? Does "the organization's business goals" mean more than "the business's goals" or "the organization's goals"? Or even just "our goals" or "your goals"?

I usually shorten first drafts by *at least* a third.  (Be ruthless with adjectives.)

George Bernard Shaw said it best: "If I had more time, I'd write you a shorter letter."